# Removing three highlighted dots in Rider JetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlight, rider, syntaxhighlighter

I'm using the latest version of Rider by JetBrains for my C# projects. I like very much the color scheme of IntelliJ Idea and their shortcuts but my C# code in Rider gets highlighted by 3 dots when the IDE finds a quickfix. I want to change 3 dots rider's highlighting to the highlighting of IntelliJ Idea, or just remove the 3 dots. Do you know guys how can I achieve this ?

[rider highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcsR2.png)

[intellij highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAmmu.png)

Answer (score 0):

These three dots does not come from a color schema, they are indicating some potential troubles in your code. Namely, it is "Replace built-in type reference with a CLR type name or keyword".

Disable this inspection in "Preferences | Editor | Inspection Settings | Inspection Severity | C#" as shown to get rid of the unwanted warning.

[Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alilz.png)

If you want to get rid of other warnings, hover your mouse of "..." and you will see the inspection name. Now, press Shift+Shift and type the inspection name. Click on the appeared option to open this inspection setting.